# Objects shown in locals while debugging does not match what I get in the editor

Tags: c#, debugging, intellisense, locals

As a part of a customisation to an existing application I need to create an object in one class and use that in another class. Now, I have created the object in the class and when debugging I can drill through the locals tree and see the object a couple of steps down the tree. Simplified, it looks a bit like this:

objectA

--> objectB

----> objectC

Object C is found in Object B which is found in Object A

I thought that I could get my object basically by doing a objectA.objectB.objectC but the problem is that when I try that objectA does not have objectB although the debugger clearly says otherwise.

A few screen dumps:

[The debugger shows that the eft object has a path to the SessionProcessor object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sugu3.jpg)

[Intellisense does not offer me the EftServices I saw in the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ldo.jpg)

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

.søren

Comment: You should show your code for this classes. The best guess is that some of the fields are not public.

Comment: Hi petric, I have added a couple of screen shots now.

Comment: So you're you want to access SessionProcessor ?

Comment: Sorry I tried to answer but I don't understand what you're asking. You should be more specific using actual class names if it's in the Microsoft Dynamics frameworks.

Comment: I'd like to get the SessionProcessor object from a blank operation. I can see it in the debugger but not when trying to access it from the editor. The two screen dumps should explain it a bit.